# Unused local variable warning in self-executing anonymous function

Tags: javascript, eclipse

Eclipse generates 'The local variable is never read' when a variable is declared inside the self-executing anonymous function, and does not when it is declared in the global scope.

Self-executing example:

```
var MODULE = {};

(function (module) {

  // THIS LINE GENERATES WARNING
  var FOO_BAR_ANON = {};

  function Foo ( ) {

    if ( this instanceof Foo ) {

      // THIS IS WHERE VARIABLE IS USED
      this.fooBar = FOO_BAR_ANON;

    } else {
      return new Foo( );
    }
  }

  module['Foo'] = Foo;

})( MODULE );
```

Global scope example, no warning generated:

```
var MODULE = {};

var FOO_BAR_GLOBAL = {};

function FooGlobal ( ) {

  if ( this instanceof FooGlobal ) {

    this.fooBar = FOO_BAR_GLOBAL;

  } else {
    return new FooGlobal( );
  }
}

MODULE['FooGlobal'] = FooGlobal;
```

Could you, please, explain, why the warning is generated in the first place, and how to silence it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a known bug in Eclipse:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=351470

`FOO_BAR_ANON` is captured when you define function Foo within the anonymous function and reference `FOO_BAR_ANON` within Foo.  See [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) documentation.

Here's the example used in the bug report (at the end of the page):

```
(function() {
    var moveCaretTimer = -1;

    function setMask() {
        (function() {
            function focusEvent() {
                var moveCaret = function() {
                // empty
                };
                clearTimeout(moveCaretTimer);
                moveCaretTimer = setTimeout(moveCaret, 0);
            }
        })();
    }

    setMask.storageKey = storageKey;
})();
```

`moveCaretTimer` is marked as never read, its occurrences not highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember my Javascript correctly, the reason it works in the Global is because in your self-executing example, the variable FOO_BAR_ANON is outside of the function Foo's scope. When I enabled my JS validator in Eclipse RSA, your line

this.fooBar = FOO_BAR_GLOBAL;

could not resolve to a value, because as far as foo is concerned, the variable doesn't exist within its scope.

Also, to suppress this, my options for Javascript were under: 
Project->Properties->JavaScript->Validation->Errors and Warnings.

Here you can customize what warnings are thrown or ignored.  It may be different in your version of Eclipse.